# How do the def2-SV, def2-SV(P), and def2-SVP basis sets differ?

Tags: computational-chemistry, basis-set

I am trying to calculate the energy of complex molecules with DFT and have a question about the Ahlrichs (Karlsruhe) def2 basis sets.

What is the difference  between the def2-SV, def2-SV(P), and def2-SVP?
Do they only differ in whether the basis set includes split valence polarization or not?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE!  If you haven't already, please take a minute to look over the [help center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) and [tour page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand our guidelines and question policies.

Comment: If you want quantifyable results, you should not use SVP basis sets. They have a very broad error distribution and are generally not really usable for accurate results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Def2-SVP has the polarisation functions on all atoms, -SV(P) does not have these functions on the hydrogen atoms and -SV does without them.

In future, you can check on the [EMSL Basis Set Exchange](https://www.basissetexchange.org/) It wouldn't give you an answer explicitly, but you can view the basis set for different atoms and see how the different sets vary.

A side note - If your 'complex molecules' aren't too large, consider the larger Def2-TZVP basis set. Errors at the Def2-SVP level can be several kcal which may significantly impact your study. As an alternative, consider the PC-n family of basis sets from Frank Jensen. If the Def2-TZVP set is too large, the double-zeta PC-1 might work well.